# getting error in if __name__=="__main__": and i have created two files which one is score.py where I coded and in second two.py where import score.py

Tags: python

File "C:\Users\sande\OneDrive\Desktop\two.py", line 8, in 
import score.py

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'score.py'; 'score' is not a package

Comment: Drop the `.py`!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by using this:

```
import score
```

If this `score.py` is not is not in same folder as your `two.py` then visit [How to import the class within the same directory or sub directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory) to solve that issue.

Comment: they are in the same folder.

Comment: @SandeepKumar Yeah! `import score` will work then. :) isn't it working?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use import scope.py, if you are having problem importing try **import scope** (if both the files are in the same directory) or if the files are in different directories you can use the sys module in python

```
# importing sys
import sys

# adding Folder_2 to the system path
sys.path.insert(0, '/C:/Users/sande/OneDrive/{drive/folder}/scope.py')

# importing the functions/class
```

If you are still getting the error, try removing

> if **name** == "**main**":

Comment: Thank you to all my friends who gave me the right solution to my problem, and I have sorted out my problem

Comment: Happy to help Sandeep