# module not found Error: Cannot resolve module 'opensubtitles'

Tags: python, testing, dataset

I did everything to resolve this issue.
I am a beginner with python. My Folder structure:

```
├─conversational-datasets-master-opensubtitles/ 
└── conversational-datasets-master/ 
└── opensubtitles/
  └── create_data.py
  └── create_data_test.py
```

- in opensubtitles folder, I have two files
- The first one is create_data.py which is for the train
- the second one is create_data_test.py which is for testing

So the Question is
Whenever I am trying to run the create_data_test.py it shows this error (module not found error)

```
File "C:\Users\suppo\Desktop\conversational-datasets-master-opensubtitles\conversational-datasets-master\opensubtitles\create_data_test.py", line 15, in <module>
    import opensubtiles.create_data.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'opensubtiles'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your import statement in `create_data_test.py`
from:

```py
import opensubtitles.create_data.py
```

to:

```py
import create_data
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just got a typo here ...

import opensubti t les.create_data.py

There are several posts of importing modules and classes in python. Take a look here... hope it helps

[How to import the class within the same directory or sub directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory)

Comment: Even after fixing the typo it won't work

Comment: try to import create_data.py without the folder... your python files are in the same folder. import create_data.py

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @SujalSingh https://github.com/PolyAI-LDN/conversational-datasets

Comment: @RaphaelAmorminio https://github.com/PolyAI-LDN/conversational-datasets

Answer (score 0):

```
from opensubtitles import create_data
from opensubtitles import create_data_test
```

This should work.
But if you are in the root folder, you may have to use joinpath, since there are hyphens in the folder names.