# How to resolve Python Module Not Found Error?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I am facing a problem in importing modules in python. I looked for a solution and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70577938/module-not-found-error-cannot-resolve-module-opensubtitles). but this did not worked either.

My Directory is as follows

->MyScrapper 
 --->MyScrapper
 ----->db_connection.py 
 --->Video_Scrapper 
 -----> video_scrapper.py
 --->Blogs_Scrapper
 -----> blogs_scrapper.py

I want to import `db_connection.py` in `video_scrapper.py` as well as `blogs_scrapper.py`. I have tried to import it as `from MyScrapper.db_connection import DBConnection`. It throws a `ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'MyScrapper'`. I have also tried using `from db_connection import DBConnection` and `import DBConnection` but none of them worked.

Please Help!!

Comment: There are 2 MyScrapper folders here. Rename one of them to be something else. Ideally, don't have the same names for the python files and parent folders.

Comment: ahan... let me do that too.!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import the class within the same directory or sub directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory)

Comment: May be you just need to specify correct root directory for project?

Comment: @rustyhu that's the way I am trying to import classes. but they don't work on the production server.

Comment: @IhorKonovalenko how to do that?

Comment: @AsadMehmood It depends on you IDE

Answer (score 0):

When importing a module in python, it will search the module in [this order](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

- build-in module
- script in the current directory
- PATHPYTHON
- installation-dependent default

So, you need to add the MyScrapper module to the search path. If you use a virtual environment, you can add your project root directory into the PYTHONPATH, by modify the PYTHONPATH in the Scripts\activate.bat file, like this:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%VIRTUAL_ENV%\src;%PYTHONPATH%
```

I use the virtual environment, and my project struct is:
|--Include
|--Lib
|--Scripts
|--src

My source files are in the src directory.