# How do I import a package and run a module in it, it will import another module in the package

Tags: python

Module `b` in the package will import module `a`. If I import this package in c.py and run module `b`, it will report an error.

> No module named 'a'

How should I modify it?

a.py:

```
def a():
    print('a')
```

b.py:

```
import a
a.a()
```

c.py:

```
import package.a
import package.b
```

Directory structure:

```
main/
    c.py
    package/
       __init__.py
        b.py
        a.py
```

Comment: `from . import a`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import the class within the same directory or sub directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a class of problems