# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'x' when I try to import a module inside x file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a folder called 'x'.
Inside this folder I have a `__main__.py` file.
In this file I have `from x import xapi`.
'xapi.py' is in the folder 'x'.

When I type on the terminal `pipenv run start`, I get an error:
`No module named 'x'`

I tried changing `from x import xapi` to `from . import xapi` and `import xapi`. It didn't work either.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory