# import inside a python package - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I'm trying to build a package where specific modules call other modules. Example of the structure of the package:

```
provapackage/
├── main.py
└── pippo
    ├── derivative_functions.py
    ├── functions_pippo.py
    └── __init__.py
```

content of the functions_pippo module:

```
def add(x,y):
    return x+y
```

content of the `derivative_functions` module:

```
from functions_pippo import add

def add_lst(l):
    n=0
    for i in l:
        n = add(n,i)
    return n
```

content of the `main.py` file:

```
from pippo.derivative_functions import add_lst

lst = [1,2,3,4]
print(add_lst(lst))
```

when I run `main.py` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/g/Documents/provapackage/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pippo.derivative_functions import add_list
  File "/home/g/Documents/provapackage/pippo/derivative_functions.py", line 1, in <module>
    from functions_pippo import add
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'functions_pippo'
```

It seems like python cannot find the `functions_pippo` module even if it's in the same folder. But when I run `derivative_functions.py` I don't gat any error message. Is it an import problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28392732/7960407)

`from .functions_pippo import add`
not
`from functions_pippo import add`