# Signal Plotting with Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, signal-processing, python-ggplot

I have been trying to plot a certain signal on python but it keeps giving me an error message I don't know how to solve it

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import mysignals as Sig

style.use('ggplot')
style.use('dark_background')
f,pltr_arr=plt.subplots(3,sharex=True)

pltr_arr[0].plot(sig.lnputSignal_1KHz_15kHz,color='magenta')
pltr_arr[0].set_title('subplot 1',color='magenta')

pltr_arr[1].plot(sig.InputSignal_1kHz_15kHz,color='yellow')
pltr_arr[1].set_title('Subplot 1', color='yellow')

pltr_arr[2].plot(sig.InputSignal_1kHz_15lkHz,color='green')
pltr_arr[2].set_title('Subplot 1',color='green')
```

above is the code of what I tried and below is the error message

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9776\3731026071.py in 
1 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
2 from matplotlib import style
----> 3 import mysignals as Sig
4
5 style.use('ggplot')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysignals'

Comment: What is `mysignals`?

Comment: the name of the dataset

Answer (score 1):

You imported as "Sig" (*import mysignals as Sig*)

but you're trying to plot as sig. (small "s")

Answer (score 0):

Your error is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysignals'`.

This error occurred since there is no python module named mysignals.py in the same directory or in installed through pip (see `pip list`).

See [this for detailed instructions on how to import local files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory)

Comment: A link to an answer is not an answer. If a question is answered already on Stack Overflow, it should be closed as a duplicate