# Multiple files inside Azure function(python app)

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function python app deployed which makes use of multiple python files from the codebase.
Currently the structure is as follows :

```
├── HttpExample
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── function.json
├── getting_started.md
├── host.json
├── local.settings.json
├── requirements.txt
└── shared_code
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── prep_backup.py
    ├── final_execution.py
    ├── final_helper.py
    ├── file_info.py
    └── requirements.txt
```

In my HttpExample, inside the **init**.py, I call my function to do the work as follows:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
from shared_code import final_execution

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    final_execution.run_function() # fails here

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

But the `final_execution` makes use of import statements pointing to

```
from prep_backup import func1,func2
```

But the above block fails as :

```
Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prep_backup'. Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module.
```

All the necessary public packages used are listed in the requeirement.txt.

Any suggestions to work around this?

Comment: Change the project structure like [this](https://i.imgur.com/a3YBtd9.png).

Answer (score 0):

Since your prep_backup.py is within the same folder(shared_code) as the caller module(final_execution.py), you can try importing the function like this instead(put a '.' in front of the module name). This is true for Python 3 onwards.

```
from .prep_backup import func1,func2
```

This has been mentioned in the existing SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory).