# python import at same folder

Tags: python, import, pep8

If import an file in another file in the same folder.

file structure:

```
.
├── b
│   ├── c.py
│   ├── d.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── __init__.py
```

in d.py:

```
import b.c
print "import successfully"
```

**update 1**:

I use both

```
python d.py
```

and:

```
python b/d.py
```

the program cannot run and raise a ImportError.

To solve the problem, I use

```
    sys.path.insert(0, realpath(path_join(dirname(__file__), '../')))
```

However, It doesn't seems like the standard way.

Like some famous project: tornado or some what, always using this structure. but don't have the insert line.

autotest tools such as sniffer, autonose can run such structure if the import sentence is in a unittest file.

I don't know why.

PEP328 or PEP366 don't give me a great solution about this.

PEP8 recommend me to do things like this way.

The question also occur when import another module (in another file)
such as:

```
├── a
│   ├── e.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── b
│   ├── c.py
│   ├── d.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
```

Comment: This answer [exists here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6098238), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/456491)

Comment: @invert I see this method, and it can do the thing. But someone's code run succuessfully in this way. but don't have insert path sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `python b/d.py` instead of `python d.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Vinayak's answer works perfectly for Python v3.3.2.
If a bunch of non-OOP Python modules exist in a directory 'dir', one can successfully import any of the methods from any of the files existing in 'dir' into a file (also existing in 'dir').

Answer (score -1):

According to PEP328 the following code should work.

```
from . import c
```

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: This gives me: `"ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package"`

Comment: @invert maybe you shuold add from __future __ import absolute_path in your file. relative path is a python 3 feature.

Comment: @Vinayak-Kolagi relative path is not recommended, do you have some ideas to treat module as modules but not in a system way?