# Having Trouble with Import Statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

My current projects are structured like so.

```
python/
    __init__.py
    project_1/
        __init__.py
        program_1.py
    project_2/
        __init__.py
        program_2.py
    project_3/
        __init__.py
        program_3.py
```

I wanted to import a class from project_3/program_3.py, called INFO, from both project_1/program_1.py and project_2/program_2.py.  In both my program_1.py and program_2.py, I've tried the following import statements that didn't work.

**Edit** - I typically "cd" into project_1 and run my program_1.py from there.

```
from project_3.program_3 import INFO

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./program_1.py", line 43, in <module>
    from project_3.program_3 import INFO
ImportError: No module named 'project_3'

from python.project_3.program_3 import INFO

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./program_1.py", line 43, in <module>
    from python.project_3.program_3 import INFO
ImportError: No module named 'python'
```

The only way for me to import class INFO into program_1.py and program_2.py is by copying program_3.py in both program_1 and program_2's folder.  My import in program_1 and program_2's statement would become:

```
python/
    __init__.py
    project_1/
        __init__.py
        program_1.py
        program_3.py
    project_2/
        __init__.py
        program_2.py
        program_3.py
    project_3/
        __init__.py
        program_3.py

from program_3 import INFO
```

This is quite inconvenience because now I have to update program_3.py in all 3 locations.  Assuming my the way I structured my project folder is retarded:

- What's the correct/best way to structure my folders so that I could call program_3.py from program_1/2.py?
- If there's nothing wrong with my current structure, how do I correctly import the INFO class into program_1/2.py?

I have read the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages%22Python%20Documentation%22) but it didn't say anything regarding importing classes from one subfolder to another.  I also looked at another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456481/cant-get-python-to-import-from-a-different-folder%22post%22) from Stack Overflow as well but it didn't have the same structure as mine.

**Update 1** - It's important to note that I'm merely using project_1/2 as folder to organized my projects.  I originally had **init**.py in all my folders because I have no clue what I'm doing.  The only module/package that I wanted to import in my project_1/program_1.py is from project_3/program_3.py.  Example:

```
python/
    project_1/
        program_1.py
    project_2/
        program_2.py
    project_3/
        __init__.py
        program_3.py
```

Comment: Change directory in each python script to the python 
root directory`os.chdir('./python')`  and then handle imports from there

Answer (score 1):

When using submodules, you need to use relative imports. In the example provided, importing `program_3` from `program_1` should be :

```
from ..project_3 import program_3
```

and then you can use the `INFO` class: `program_3.INFO`.

This works if your executable file is outside the script, that is the file which uses the module `python` in the example should be outside the `python` module.

If parts of the `python` package  are executed as a script, the `-m` option should be passed to the interpreter:

```
python3 -m python.project_1.program_1
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I did a bit differently but similar by doing "from ..project_3.program_3 import INFO".  The error I got was "SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import."

Comment: Is the file you are running inside the module itself?. If this is the case, use `-m` option such as `python -m python.project_1.program_1`

Comment: I typically cd into project_1 and run ./program_1.py from there. If I tried to run it with the -m option, I get the following error:
python3.5 -m python.project_1.program_1.py
/usr/local/bin/python3.5: Error while finding spec for 'python.project_1.program_1.py' (ImportError: No module named 'python')

Comment: You need to cd to the directory which contains the outer module `python`, then you can run your program as in the updated answer. If you really want to run it from within program_1, you will need to change the path from within the program or something like that...

Comment: @dreamzboy in general, directly executing code from within packages (folders that have an `__init__.py` within) is wrong and very likely to cause problems.

Comment: @Nick, what's the proper way to run it or "mobilized" program_3.py to be used across my other projects?  I guess I didn't understand the purpose of __init__.py; therefore, I removed it from python, project_1/2, and only kept it in project_3.  The python, project_1/2, are just folders where I organized my python scripts.  They're not module/packages.  The only module/package that I wanted to use is project_3/program_3.py.

Answer (score 0):

The previous solution provides me the same error.

I found a fix by using sys:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')

from project_3 import program_3
...
```

This way, you setup 'python' folder as reference (in your case it's the parent folder but you can select the path you want)

I hope it helps,

Comment: I have updated my answer so that it works when running scripts within the module.

Comment: Thanks.  This works but of course PEP8 doesn't like the fact that the import statement is below the sys.path.append ('../') statement.  It's definitely better than my work around but I prefer following the "standard" to keep things neat if there's an alternative.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the only solution I found on others forums. They provide more elegant way to define the path but it's the same fix. Please share if you got another solution (I'm also interested :) )

Comment: I ended up doing the workaround where I moved my program_1/2.py under python/ directory and was able to use from project_3 import program_3.py with no errors.  Your solution is definitely clever but in my opinion it's more of a hack than a solution. If I have different versions of program_1, I'll just move it back into the project_1 folder and continue to develop the original program_1 under the python directory.