# Importing a class in another folder

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem with python directories.

I have structure like:

- python

  - modules

    - algorithms

      - cyphers

        - morse.py
  - tests

    - algorithms

      - cyphers

        - test_morse.py

When I try to import module in test I get a module not found error.
I am trying to import like:

```
parent_dir_name = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(parent_dir_name + "/../../../")

from modules.algorithms.cyphers.morse import *
```

I have also init files in all directories.
I am trying to run tests like:

```
> python -m unittest discover ./tests
```

Comment: this appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456481/cant-get-python-to-import-from-a-different-folder and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

It is customary to use [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html)

```
from ....modules.algorithms.ciphers.morse import *
```

This ensures that you import the right Morse file, otherwise you risk importing some module named Morse that you've installed.

Here's two examples to illustrate relative imports, say you have a file named simulation.py that has the line

```
from .animals import Herbivore
```

In it. This will import the Herbivore class from a file in the same directory as the simulation.py file

Now imagine that you have a folder named tests, in this folder you have a file named test_animals.py, which has the line

```
from ..animals import Herbivore
```

This will import the Herbivore class from a file named animals.py located in the folder above the tests folder.

Finally, note that (at least for Python 3.6) can't run a file that uses relative imports, only import it.

Comment: If I use this I get error:
Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package

Answer (score -1):

If you mark the directories as modules with `__init__.py`, you should just be able to import modules via

```
from modules.algorithms.cyphers import morse
```