# How do we import a module high in a project structure into a file that's at a low level? (Python 3.6 +)

Tags: python-3.x, module, path, package, directory-structure

Suppose we have the following project structure:

```
E:\demo_proj\
        utilities_package\
                __init__.py
                util_one.py
                util_two.py
        demo_package\
                __init__.py
                demo_sub_package\
                        __init__.py
                        demo_sub_sub_package\
                               demo_file.py
```

What is a sensible way for `demo_file.py` to import from `utilities_package`?

The `utilities_package` is in a much higher level directory than `demo_file.py`.

Although it is not shown in the little diagram I gave above, suppose that  `utilities_package` is used everywhere throughout the project. It is not sensible to make `utilities_package` a sub-directory of `demo_sub_sub_package`

Some similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456481/cant-get-python-to-import-from-a-different-folder) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder).

The asker of the first question neglected to include a `__init__.py` in their packages. That is not an issue in my case.

The answers given to the the second  question linked-to above are problematic:

- Most of the answers are quite old. For example, `Loader.load_module` was  deprecated after Python 3.4
- Most of the answers are specific to the question in that they only go up one directory, whereas, I would like to go up several levels.
- Some of the answers are high-level descriptions without code. Other answers have the opposite problem: they contain ugly-looking code, but don't bother to explain it.

I am open to solutions which require restructuring the project. I'm also interested in solutions which leave the project structure intact, but which insert the relevant code into `demo_file.py`

Comment: What is the file you will end up executing? If this is a properly maintained package, this should be at `\demo_proj\main.py` or something.

Answer (score 0):

It already has the very epic solution for your problems. Please refer there: [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time). Just as a notation, the python3 and python2 have the totally different definitions for the relative and absolute import. For version 3+, any modules import directly using `import module_name` are treated as the absolute importation, which means this module must be included in the `sys.path`. Otherwise, for any modules import like `from one_module import something` or `from . import something` are treated like the relative importation. The `dot-notation` represent the current directory. However, any module is executed directly by itself, it will lose its namespace, instead it will always be treated as `__main__`, and all the files in the same directory will automatically add to `sys.path` by default. Hope it will help you.