# Can not import class from another folder

Tags: python, airflow

I have a similar issue as this [Can't get Python to import from a different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456481/cant-get-python-to-import-from-a-different-folder)  The solution there doesn't solve my issue.

I'm working with Airflow lib. The lib updated one of the operators and since I can not at this time upgrade the my Airflow version I want to manually download the operator `.py` file and use it in my code manualy.

```
airflow
    -dags
        --mydag.py
    -AddedOperators
        --sagemaker_tuning_operator.py
        --__init__.py   (empty file)
```

The `sagemaker_tuning_operator.py` is this file:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/sagemaker_tuning_operator.py

It contains the class `SageMakerTuningOperator`

In my `mydag.py` I do:

```
from AddedOperators.sagemaker_tuning_operator import SageMakerTuningOperator
```

When Airflow try to parse `mydag.py` I get:

> No module named AddedOperators.sagemaker_tuning_operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your project directory is in your system path or not. You can can check it as follows:

```
import sys

print(sys.path)
```

> Note that when running a Python script, sys.path doesn’t care what
>   your current “working directory” is. It only cares about the path to
>   the script. For example, if my shell is currently at the Airflow/
>   folder and I run python ./dags/mydag.py, then sys.path includes
>   Airflow/dags/ but NOT Airflow/

If you project directory is not in sys path, you can do following:

- Include it dynamically.

  ```
  import sys
  sys.path.insert(0, 'path/to/your/')

  # import your module now
  ```
- Import all required modules in your project root folder in some file like app.py and then call from here.

Comment: It wasn't in sys.path. I did:   sys.path.insert(0, '/home/ubuntu/airflow')   still doesn't work. same error

Comment: Adding path dynamically is working fine for me. Can you show what you have done?