# How to import from sub directory Python?

Tags: python, import

I have strcture of my program like this : [image]

I want to import some functions in the examples/borrow.py file from src/v1/lend/costants/testnetCostants.py file and from src/v1/lend/borrow.py file how can I do this in a proper way ?

I try this structure but it didn't work :

```
from src.v1.lend.borrow import prepareAddEscrowTransactions, prepareBorrowTransactions, prepareRepayTransaction
from src.v1.lend.costants.testnetCostants import TestnetOracle, TestnetReserveAddress, TestnetTokenPairs
from config import algodClient, sender
```

I receive this error `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'"`

thanks all for your help

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456481/cant-get-python-to-import-from-a-different-folder

Answer (score 0):

First of all as a friendly advice, for efficient code management, please use a more organized file structure like this:

[file structure example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnKO2.png)

Then create an venv for every practical project and install appropriate reqiurements. Check the [notebook](https://github.com/pytopia/CS-Tutorial/blob/main/01.%20Python/00.%20Before%20You%20Start/02%20Conda%20Environments.ipynb).

After all if you use VScode, change the interpreter to your specific env:

[right bottom corner of your vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vp5id.png)

> After this, you should not see any warning in your VScode for imports if you
> enter correct path and install packages completely.

Finally for running:

1. In your terminal, activate the project env (if your packagemanager is conda, use `conda activate your_env_name`)
2. Go to your project directory and use `export PYTHONPATH=${PWD}`
3. Then use `python src/utils/main.py` or your own file path.

> it would be better to mention that your modular imports have no problem, if your names and structure are correct by the way. Check the [link](https://github.com/pytopia/CS-Tutorial/tree/main/01.%20Python/03.%20Modular%20Programming) if it is helpful.

Comment: I made all of this but when I run my program it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'", how can I remove this error ?

Comment: I told you in my structure advice! please read it again. when you want to import some module from a higher level in your filesystem structure, you have to address it from the top dir. in your case, `from examples.src.v1.lend.borrow import something`